# How can I plot quadrilateral patches with pcolor in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, patch

I am running into a problem with `pcolor()` from matplotlib. I want to plot patches which have a quadrilateral shape. (They do have a  non regular shape, but do have 4 corners and are not overlapping).
To demonstrate my problem, here is a minimal code which produces unexpected behavior.

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

x = [0, 1]
y = [0, 2]
val = [[1]]
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(x, y)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=[10, 10])

ax = plt.subplot(2, 1, 1)
yy[1,0] =2.9
#displays a 1x2 rectangle
ax.pcolor(xx, yy, val, edgecolors='black')

ax = plt.subplot(2, 1, 2)
yy[1,0] =3
#displays the expected 1x3(x2) trapezoid
ax.pcolor(xx, yy, val, edgecolors='black')

plt.show()
```

(We are expecting a trapezoid with height 2.9 but it outputs a rectangle with 2x1. The second example with height 3 works fine)

Here is the output

[image]

Also, using `pcolormesh`, the same problem occurs.

Is this a bug or am I just blind?

Comment: Can you describe more what exactly is unexpected about the result?

Comment: I added the output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the data type of `xx` and `yy` is `int64`. So when you attempt the assignment `yy[1, 0] = 2.9` it is cast to an `int`, resulting in `yy[1, 0] == 2`.

The solution is to change the datatype to `float`, simplest way to do that is using `numpy.ndarray.astype`:

```py
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

x = [0, 1]
y = [0, 2]
val = [[1]]
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(x, y)

xx = xx.astype('float64')
yy = yy.astype('float64')

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=[10, 10])

ax = plt.subplot(2, 1, 1)
yy[1,0] = 2.9
ax.pcolor(xx, yy, val, edgecolors='black')

ax = plt.subplot(2, 1, 2)
yy[1,0] = 3
ax.pcolor(xx, yy, val, edgecolors='black')
```

This will give the expected result

[image]